# PHP bug (lambda function with use)

Tags: php, lambda

I think I stumbled across a bug in PHP. However, to be sure, I am asking here first.

```
$k=0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/./', function($groups) use ($k) {
    return $k++;
}, 'xxxxxx');
```

Script output: **000000**

Expected output: **012345**

Am I missing something?

Comment: ya know .. some people actually read documentation, before they start reporting "bugs".

Comment: I read It, but that is easily overlooked. Such importat thing should be more clearly emphasized. Guess I sould have written "bug" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$k` is bound to the closure by value, not by reference. So it will always be the same between multiple closure calls.

You can also pass it by reference using `&$k`. Note that this will also modify the `$k` value outside the closure.

Comment: Beat me by a minute. A well earned +1.

Comment: This explains it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function is called every time a match is found, the state of $k is not preserved during (hence, the closure).

Try passing it by reference, or use a global.